Factorization of $a^n + b^n$
So, I have read countless math articles which reference the following:
$$ a^n + b^n = (a+b)(a^{n-1} - a^{n-2}b + ... - ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1}) $$ when n is odd.
I had always wondered how we could we derive such a statement.
Well, intuitively, it makes a lot of sense for me.
My first approach was to test for certain odd values of n.
For n = 1, $a + b = (a+b)(1) = (a+b).$
For n = 3, $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$.
$$ a^3 + b^3 = a^3 + b^3$$ after we cancel some terms.
For n = 5, $a^5 + b^5 = (a+b)(a^4 - a^3b + a^2b^2 -ab^3 + b^4)$.
This was also true by simplification.
I have tested several values including: 9, 13, 15, 21, 39, etc.(completely losing my sanity, luckily I used a polynomial expansion calculator)
All turned out to be true.
But how we could prove it for the general case? Any help is appreciated.
Additionally, adding to this, I have searched on Approach Zero, a math search engine, for the same exact formula, but the articles it referenced used the formula, and didn't derive this. Adding to this, I searched on MSE search engine. No result. I have tried my best to avoid duplicates.

The polynomial $f(a,b)=a^n-b^n$ has a root, for $b=-a$, because
$$
f(a,-a)=a^n-a^n=0
$$
for all odd $n\ge 1$.
Hence $f$ has a factor $a+b$.

And do you do long division to prove the other part?

I have used long division to successfully get the other factor.

An alternative approach is to use induction. Prove a base case and assume
$$(a+b)\left(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2} b + \cdots - ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1}\right)=a^n+b^n$$
for some odd $n$. Now
\begin{align}(a+b)\left(a^{n+1}-a^n b + \cdots - ab^n + b^{n+1}\right) &=(a+b)\left(a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}\right)-ab(a+b)\left(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2} b + \cdots - ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1}\right) \\
&=(a+b)\left(a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}\right)-ab\left(a^n+b^n\right)\\
&=a^{n+2}+b^{n+2}
\end{align}

Wow! That is fantastic. Yes, kind of me, trying different values of n, was me trying to establish an induction hypothesis.
Your approach is smart.
Thank you for your help!
